# Symfony Form Ad fields after submit

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a recherche form that contains a text field

When submitting the form, the result is an array that contains the list of search contents and the list of possible filters for that search.

After submitting, I want to add fields (these filters) dynamically to my form type

Comment: What have you done so far? Please post some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look into [Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html) documentation.

Quote from this doc:

> For example, if you wish to register a function to the FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT event, the following code lets you add a field, depending on the request values:

Comment: Thanks

Yes I know it's the event to use, but I do not need the request, I need the result of the form submission

Comment: @Karim sorry, misunderstood. 
Could you please provide more details about what are you want to reach and when? It's not clear to me.